# Divs com cores zebrada e propriedade order

Tags: css

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```css
.pai{
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.filho{
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.ordem1{order:1}
.ordem2{order:2}
.ordem3{order:3}
.ordem4{order:4}
.ordem5{order:5}

.filho:nth-child(odd) {background: #e0e0e0;}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
   <div class="filho ordem5">Zebra5 (cinza)</div>
   <div class="filho ordem3">Zebra3 (cinza)</div>
   <div class="filho ordem4">Zebra4 (branca)</div>
   <div class="filho ordem2">Zebra2 (branca)</div>
   <div class="filho ordem1">Zebra1 (cinza)</div>
</div>
```

Porém gostaria que as divs ficassem zebradas de acordo com a propriedade `order` do css, na mesma sequencia.
Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Tu queres que fiquem alternando entre cinza e branco? No caso, não seria melhor colocar a cor dentro da classe do ordem? Ou já receber ordenado?

Comment: Sim, zebradas entre cinza e branco obedecendo a propriedade order do css.

Comment: Já recebo ordenado

Comment: Com JavaScript vc consegue ordenar as divs pela classe `ordem` sem ter que usar o `order` do flex. Veja um exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/g95f712u/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem uma forma de fazer, a única ressalva é que vc saiba a altura do filho. Tendo um valor fixo pro filho vc pode construir um `background` no pai. A ideia é não usar o bg no filho onde a ordem pode variar, mas sim no pai que vai crescer de forma controlada já que vc sabe a altura do filho.

Repare que mesmo deletando um filho no do meio, mesmo assim a ordem das listras segue coerente. Ela se "adapta" ao filho independente da ordem...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que temos aqui é um pai com um `repeat-liner-gradient`, onde cada faixa de cor te a altura do filho, no caso `30px + borda`. Então não importa a ordem ou quantos filhos vc tem o gradiente listrado no fundo sempre vei encaixar nos filhos.

Segue o código

```css
.pai{
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, #ccc 0px, #ccc 31px, #fff 31px, #fff 62px);
  background-size: 80% 100%;
  background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
}
  
.filho{
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ordem1{order:1}
.ordem2{order:2}
.ordem3{order:3}
.ordem4{order:4}
.ordem5{order:5}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  <div class="filho ordem5">Zebra5 (cinza)</div>
  <div class="filho ordem3">Zebra3 (cinza)</div>
  <div class="filho ordem4">Zebra4 (branca)</div>
  <div class="filho ordem2">Zebra2 (branca)</div>
  <div class="filho ordem1">Zebra1 (cinza)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado! `It works like a charm`.

Comment: @PedroAugusto alguns chamaria isso de gambiarra, eu prefiro chamar de recurso tecnológico 